# Write multiple excel/csv files from a large data.frame

Tags: r, excel, csv, xlsx, xlsxwriter

I have a large data frame of over 500,000 rows. I wish to export it to multiple excel/csv files with a certain row limit (e.g. 100,000 rows).

My solution is:

```
library(openxlsx)
write.xlsx(df[1:100000,], "path")
write.xlsx(df[100001:200000,], "path")
write.xlsx(df[200001:300000,], "path")
write.xlsx(df[300001:400000,], "path")
write.xlsx(df[400001:500000,], "path")
```

Is there any elegant way to do it?
Thanks

Comment: When you say elegant, do you really mean "concise"?

Comment: Yes, I wish to do this with a function to apply the logic over extremely large dataset.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try something like...

```
breaks <- split(1:nrow(df), ceiling(seq_along(1:nrow(df))/1e5))
lapply(breaks, 
   function(x)                  
     write.xlsx(
          df[x,],
          paste0("path",substr(x[1],1,1),".xlsx")
)
```

Change 1e5 to change the number of rows to include in each break. Should output something like `path1.xlsx`,`path2.xlsx`, ...

Answer (score 3):

```
batchSize=100; # number of rows in single output file
filename="file_name";  # prefix of output file

chunks=split(df, floor(0:(nrow(df)-1)/batchSize))
for (i in 1:length(chunks))
{
  write.xlsx(chunks[[i]],paste0(filename,i,'.xlsx'))
}
```

Above will create file_name1.xlsx, file_name2.xlsx, .... etc. in your working directory.